# NSDateFormatter returns nil in iphone 5 ios 6.1

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Can someone tells me whats wrong with my time formatter? when i used ipod 6.0 the time formatter works. but when i used iphone 5 6.1 the time formatter returns nil.

Here are my codes regarding to the timeFormatter.

```
    NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
    [tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"];
    NSString *dateandtime = @"2013-05-27 19:00";

    //set end date and time
    NSDateFormatter *tempFormatterTo = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
    [tempFormatterTo setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"];
    NSString *dateandtimeTo = @"2013-05-27 20:00";

    NSDate *startDate = [tempFormatter dateFromString:dateandtime];
    NSDate *endDate = [tempFormatterTo dateFromString:dateandtimeTo];
```

Thanks in advance. please help me.

Comment: It should be like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this format.  `HH` used for 24 hour format.

```
  [tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
```

Answer (score 0):

here problem in your Format change it to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` also use my bellow method when you want to convert any `NSString` date to `NSDate` .. This is my custom method just paste this method in your `.m` class..

```
-(NSDate *)convertStringToDate:(NSString *) date dateFormat:(NSString*)dateFormat{
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]; 
        NSDate *nowDate = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
        [formatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];// set format here which format in string date
        date = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+0000" withString:@""];
        nowDate = [formatter dateFromString:date];
        // NSLog(@"date============================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : %@", nowDate);
        return nowDate;
}
```

and use above method like bellow...

```
 NSDate *startDate = [self convertStringToDate:@"2013-05-27 19:00" dateFormate:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
 NSDate *endDate = [self convertStringToDate:@"2013-05-27 20:00" dateFormate:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"];
NSDate* d = [df dateFromString:@"2013-05-27 19:00"];
NSLog(@"%@", d);
```